# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.name')

Tags: javascript, react-native, drag-and-drop, draggable

I use Draxview to handle drag and drop between two lists. Overall It works perfectly, but sometimes it crashes with an error message:

- TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.name') *

It's when drag the the draggable item back and forth between the two lists. But it not happends every time. Do anyone have clue of what I should do?

Here is my code:

```
  const DragUIComponent = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      
      <DraxView
      style={[styles.centeredContent, styles.draggableBox]}
      draggingStyle={styles.dragging}
      dragReleasedStyle={styles.dragging}
      hoverDraggingStyle={styles.hoverDragging}
        dragPayload={index}
        longPressDelay={150}
        key={index}
      >
         <View  style={styles.emptyView}>
           
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.name === null ? '' : item.name}</Text>
          </View>
      </DraxView>
    );
  }

  {HERE I GET THE ERROR}
  //The Receiving Zone Where I drops my draggable element
  const ReceivingZoneUIComponent = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      
      <DraxView
        style={[styles.centeredContent, styles.receivingZone]}
        receivingStyle={styles.receiving}
            renderContent={({ viewState }) => {
            try {
            const receivingDrag = viewState && viewState.receivingDrag;
            const payload = receivingDrag && receivingDrag.payload;
            return (
  
              <View style={styles.recView}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyleeRceiving}>{item.name === null ? '' : item.name}</Text>
                </View>
            );
          } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
          }
          }}
        key={index}
        onReceiveDragDrop={(event) => {
          let selected_item = dragItemMiddleList[event.dragged.payload];
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop::index', selected_item, index);
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop :: payload', event.dragged.payload);
          let newReceivingItemList = [...receivingItemList];
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop :: newReceivingItemList', newReceivingItemList);
          newReceivingItemList[index] = selected_item;
          setReceivedItemList(newReceivingItemList);

          let newDragItemMiddleList = [...dragItemMiddleList];
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop :: newDragItemMiddleList 1', newDragItemMiddleList);
          newDragItemMiddleList[event.dragged.payload] = receivingItemList[index];
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop :: newDragItemMiddleList 2', newDragItemMiddleList);
          setDragItemListMiddle(newDragItemMiddleList);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: There are a few places in the code you provided that reference item.name. Wouldn't it be easier to just add protection in the code in those places that checks if item is not null?

Comment: In what component are you getting the error? It seems that you are not passing or wrongly passing `item` prop when instantiating your component. However, I can't see that part in your code.

Comment: As @ErnestoStifano alluded, can you add the [mre] of where you're invoking these functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error will occur whenever item is undefined. You can solve this using optional chaining. So wherever you have used `item.name === null ? '' : item.name` just replace it with `item?.name || ''`

Your updated code will be:

```
const DragUIComponent = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      
      <DraxView
      style={[styles.centeredContent, styles.draggableBox]}
      draggingStyle={styles.dragging}
      dragReleasedStyle={styles.dragging}
      hoverDraggingStyle={styles.hoverDragging}
        dragPayload={index}
        longPressDelay={150}
        key={index}
      >
         <View  style={styles.emptyView}>
           
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item?.name || ''}</Text>
          </View>
      </DraxView>
    );
  }

  {HERE I GET THE ERROR}
  //The Receiving Zone Where I drops my draggable element
  const ReceivingZoneUIComponent = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      
      <DraxView
        style={[styles.centeredContent, styles.receivingZone]}
        receivingStyle={styles.receiving}
            renderContent={({ viewState }) => {
            try {
            const receivingDrag = viewState && viewState.receivingDrag;
            const payload = receivingDrag && receivingDrag.payload;
            return (
  
              <View style={styles.recView}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyleeRceiving}>{item?.name || ''}</Text>
                </View>
            );
          } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
          }
          }}
        key={index}
        onReceiveDragDrop={(event) => {
          let selected_item = dragItemMiddleList[event.dragged.payload];
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop::index', selected_item, index);
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop :: payload', event.dragged.payload);
          let newReceivingItemList = [...receivingItemList];
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop :: newReceivingItemList', newReceivingItemList);
          newReceivingItemList[index] = selected_item;
          setReceivedItemList(newReceivingItemList);

          let newDragItemMiddleList = [...dragItemMiddleList];
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop :: newDragItemMiddleList 1', newDragItemMiddleList);
          newDragItemMiddleList[event.dragged.payload] = receivingItemList[index];
          console.log('onReceiveDragDrop :: newDragItemMiddleList 2', newDragItemMiddleList);
          setDragItemListMiddle(newDragItemMiddleList);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```